# checking the stopped VM's with different resources by Powershell script

Tags: azure

How to check stopped virtual Machines with different resources by azure powershell script
iam tried to do that  script please help me

Comment: confused, Could you describe your issue clearer?

Answer (score 0):

To get status of the vm’s you can try the below script:

```
 #login 
Connect-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName 'subscription-name'
Get-AzureRmVM -Status | Format-Table
```

If you want ResourceGroup group wise you try this script:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName 'subscription-name'
$RG = "ResourceGroupName"
$VM = "vmname"
$VMStats = (Get-AzureRmVM -Name $VM -ResourceGroupName $RG -Status).Statuses
($VMStats | Where Code -Like 'PowerState/*')[0].DisplayStatus
```

Comment: Actually iam asking about   my VM's located at different locations how can I check the status of all the VM's which located in different regions

Comment: By using powershell script how can I check the status of all the VM's which are located in different regions